# Calculate, How much to vertical scroll a container to make visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div container that has height 400 and overflow true.

it has vertical scrollbar.

having more html content inside that div.

Now I want to get the scroll height of a child div so that I can scroll the scrollbar through code.

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="b1">
    // let say it's height is 200px so that next div is not visible
    </div>
    <div >
    // let say it's height is some i don't have
    </div>
    <div>

        <div id="b2">
            XYZ content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// now I want calculate, how much I should scroll to make #b2 visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use offsetTop to find the y coordinate of desired to you block, but don't forget to subtract it from the offsetTop of the parentContainer.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    b2 = document.getElementById('b2');

container.scrollTop = b2.offsetTop - container.offsetTop;
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Volter9/2zv6f/)

Good luck!